# Pegar dados de uma tabela através de uma relação N:N

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um sistema feito em PHP e MySQL onde tenho dois tipos de cadastros, professor e aluno.

Nesta plataforma, o professor pode adicionar um aluno como "amigo" e o aluno também pode adicionar um professor como "amigo". Além disso, o professor também pode adicionar um conteúdo em que SOMENTE OS ALUNOS QUE TIVEREM RELAÇÃO (adicionado como amigo) COM ESTE PROFESSOR vão poder ver quando estiverem logados.

Para fazer isso, tenho as tabelas alunos e professores, com seus respectivos dados, e também tenho uma tabela N:N chamada alunos_professores, que contém o id do aluno e do professor (já que o aluno pode ter vários professores adicionados e o professor pode ter vários alunos adicionados).

Além disso, tenho uma tabela chamada conteúdo, contendo o id do professor que adicionou este conteúdo. Quando logado como aluno, preciso pegar os CONTEÚDOS que foram adicionados pelos professores que tem relação com este aluno. Como eu faço isso usando a tabela N:N?

Comment: A sua dúvida é sobre como construir uma consulta SQL? Ou você usa algum ORM? O que você já tentou fazer? Seja mais específico e se possível inclua o código do que tentou fazer.

Comment: É uma consulta SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então quando o aluno logar, você vai buscar nessa tabela N:N alunos_professores onde o id dele aparece, e os respectivos ids dos professores, com isso você já pegou a relação de amigos dele, feito isso você vai selecionar na tabela conteúdo, os conteúdos que tem os ids dos professores que foram retornados no primeiro select. Tente fazer algo parecido com o exemplo abaixo.

```
SELECT  t1.id, t2.id_professor, t3.conteudo
        FROM (select * from alunos where id= $iduser)
        t1
        inner join (select * from alunos_professores)
        t2
        on t1.id = t2.id_aluno
        inner join(select * from conteudos)
        t3
        on t2.id_professor = t3.id_professor
```

Comment: No caso, qual seriam as tabelas t1, t2 e t3? E funciona colocar um SELECT após um FROM?

Comment: t1, t2, t3 são nomes que dei para os selects , igual o select * from alunos where id= $iduser é a t1. select * from alunos_professores é a t2, e select * from alunos_professores é a t3, e na primeira linha onde coloco t1.id, t2.id_professor, t3.conteudo vai ser o que vai aparecer como resultado dessa consulta inteira, se você quer que apareça o titulo do conteúdo por exemplo que esta na t3, no começo você tem que fazer assim: t1.id, t2.id_professor, t3.conteudo, t3.titulo, e assim sucessivamente para todos os campos que queira exibir

Comment: select após o from funciona sim, o sql entendi q vc vai pesquisa algo no resultado daquele select